# Trigger Full Calendar Refresh with Param on Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, fullcalendar

I want to trigger an refresh events with a specific parameter when selecting a value in a select box.

I have my select box defined in a grails tag:

```
<g:select name="resourceId"
                from="${Resource.list()}"
                optionKey="id"
                optionValue="name"
                onchange="refreshCalendar()"/>
```

I understand that I can trigger a JS function with the onchange item in the tag.

refreshCalendar function:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
```

My calendar is configured as:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: '${createLink(action:'loadSchedule' )}'
}
```

How can I now provide the calendar refresh function or the events item within the fullcalendar configuration with an id param selected in the select box?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know if this is the "cool" way but it is working now with this solution:

```
var source;
        function refreshCalendar(id) {
            source = '${createLink(action:'loadSchedule' )}' + '?resourceId=' + id;
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', source );
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', source );
        }
```

So the calendar is loading with the new src and later its removed